# Check if user is admin when logging in to PHP website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a login form where if you are an admin you will get logged into a different site than if you were a normal user. However, I am not sure how to do so.

In my database I have "admin" column, that is set to 0 by default. If it is 1 it would be an admin.

Here is the login code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Skriv inn et brukernavn");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Skriv inn et passord");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "Du er nå logget inn";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Feil brukernavn eller passord");
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me,

Thanks :)

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You shouldn't escape passwords before hashing them. Doing so will change the password. Since you're saving the hash, there's also no need to. You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.

Comment: At first you should add another column which is type or group where you identify user which user admin or normal user like you set 1 for  admin 0 for normal user.  When you fetch data   you can get the group or type Id and then you can passing different page by there group or type id

Comment: Other than that, just check if admin is 0 or 1 and redirect the user to the correct place. Just add an if-statement before your `header()`.

Comment: Fetch the `$results` and see if the row has 1 for `admin`.

Comment: @rowmoin - I think this sentence _"In my database I have "admin" column, that is set to 0 by default. If it is 1 it would be an admin."_ tells us that the OP already does what you suggest.

Comment: That's the thing, I am not sure how I would do that. I am very new to PHP, and most of this code is from a tutorial from a website. How do I fetch the $results?

Comment: When in doubt go to `php.net` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php.

Comment: Just check the if condition if( $results_>admin == '1'){redirect  admin page} else {normal page}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more condition to check if logged in person is admin or not like below code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) 
 {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "Du er nå logget inn";
      $details = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
      if( $details['admin'] == '1')
      {
         redirect him to admin here
        // header('location: index.php');
      }
      else if($details['admin'] == '0')
      {
         redirect him to normal page
         //header('location: index.php');
      } 
 }
```

Comment: @Lowtexx   to which page its redirecting,check that page.

Comment: I checked it, everything seems like it should be, I also tried to redirect it to another page and I still get the same issue.

Comment: print_r($details); die;add this line and show result

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: $details = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); after this line add that code

Comment: Ahhh, I managed to fix it now! the problem was that the "$result->..." was supposed to be "results" and not "result". I really appreciate your help man! Thank you! :-)